# Wordpress delivering every page as homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a wordpress install on a host and a DNS pointing to that host. The issue is that the site is being migrated from a subdirectory and that structure needs to remain intact.

So www.webpage.com/subdirectory/ now points to www.wordpress-host.com where the content is hosted.

Inside Wordpress the site URL is set to www.webpage.com/subdirectory/ and the .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirectory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

With this setup the homepage renders normal, all css and javascript load correctly.

The issue is that no matter what page/post is viewed it is always renders the homepage.

I have also create a plugin to replace all host URLs with the site URL, but when this is active every file is the homepage, so is you inspect any .css or .js file it is the HTML from the homepage.

Is there something im missing in the htaccess or another solution to get this working?

I think that the htaccess is incorrect, but im not sure how to have it work with a fake subdirectory.

-The new host is just a wordpress host, so the original site will remain on its host, but the wordpress install is being moved.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are saying the wordpress that previously installed at the `/subdirectory` now has be moved to `/`? Where is the `.htaccess` located? at `/subdirectory`? or at `/`?

Comment: Wordpress was previously installed at /subdirectory but has moved to the root of a new host, but the original URL must stay the same. The .htaccess file is at the root level

Comment: If you want to keep the original url (with subdir), why move the site to the root dir???

Comment: @Bjiorn the new host doesn't support subdirs

Comment: What kind of host that doesn't support subdirectories? Even wordpress would has its own subdirectories such as `wp-content`, 'wp-admin`, etc. If your root directory is `/var/www/html/` as root '/' on the server, all you need is to redefine the directory '/var/www/html/subdir' as your root, and install the wordpress like your old host, no?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect from `/subdirectory` to `/`, then first of all, the .htacess should be at `/subdirectory` because that will be where all the url requests coming from.

Secondly on `.htaccess` setting, the RewriteRule then should be `RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`.

Comment: I updated the description, but the new host is a pure wordpress host, so the old site will remain on its host while the wordpress install is being moved. With that there is no subdirectory but i need to fake it somehow so when traffic comes from the main URL all links and assets will be delivered from that mapping.